# Yahoo Mail is adjusting margins in HTML email

Tags: html, html-email, yahoo

I'm perplexed by what's going on so I figured S.O. might be able to help.  I have a HTML email and everything looks fine except for a couple of bullets.

Here's how it looks in Outlook, AOL, GMail:[image]

Here's how it looks in Yahoo:[image]

**Updated**
I've add `text-align` values to the `<p>` tags, but the result remains the same.

Here's my code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="16" align="left" valign="top">
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" style="outline: none; border: none;" alt=" " width="16" height="5" />
      </td>
      <td width="10" align="right" valign="top" style="color: #231F20;">
        <p style="margin: -20px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #231F20; text-align:right;">*</p>
      </td>
      <td width="492" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #231F20; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 4px;">
        <p style="margin: -20px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="16" align="left" valign="top">
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" style="outline: none; border: none;" alt=" " width="16" height="5" />
      </td>
      <td width="10" align="right" valign="top" style="color: #231F20;">
        <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #231F20; text-align:right;"><sup>&dagger;</sup></p>
      </td>
      <td width="492" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #231F20; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 4px;">
        <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;;">
          Pellentesque ipsum sem, venenatis a condimentum vitae, gravida vel neque. Suspendisse placerat sapien in leo eleifend porta. Donec ut augue vel felis condimentum aliquet. Curabitur luctus, nunc vel blandit elementum, ante lacus facilisis nulla, ac tincidunt massa quam in eros. Nulla facilisi.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.  I have no idea what's going on.  Usually Outlook is the pain to deal with, not Yahoo.

Comment: Is there a link you can provide for more information?  I just did a quick Google search and nothing really popped out.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use margin in HTML email. It is patchy in support/consistency, Outlook.com doesn't support it at all. Instead use padding on the container table cells.

Edit:
In this case you actually need neither. You can also lose the spacer images and tbody tags:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td width="26" align="right" valign="top">&bull;&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td width="492" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #231F20;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="26" align="right" valign="top">&dagger;&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td width="492" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #231F20;">
          Pellentesque ipsum sem, venenatis a condimentum vitae, gravida vel neque. Suspendisse placerat sapien in leo eleifend porta. Donec ut augue vel felis condimentum aliquet. Curabitur luctus, nunc vel blandit elementum, ante lacus facilisis nulla, ac tincidunt massa quam in eros. Nulla facilisi.
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed `<p style="margin: -20px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 11px">` to

`<p style="margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 11px">`

at

```
<p style="margin: -20px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 11px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

Comment: Those are only affecting where the words are positioned, vertically.  Plus I need those.  This is just a small snippet of a 1500-line HTML email.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just Yahoo! Outlook too

This recent article [1/29/2013] is worth reading

[Outlook.com drops margin and float support entirely](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3921/outlook.com-drops-margin-and-float-support-entirely)

Basically they didn't find a workaround for `margin` support and suggest going back to `<table>` or in some cases just `padding`.

> We also recommend going back to roots and using table cells and the cellpadding and cellspacing attributes where possible. These are the cornerstones to a truly bulletproof HTML email layout.